# Can a property observer be added after the initial declaration?

Tags: swift

For example, I'd like to call a method on a class instance that will add a `willSet` to a property.  I'd like to not have to specify the `willSet` in the declaration of the property, since I'd need to add conditional logic within the observer, and it would be unnecessarily run for every other instance that hasn't had this method called.

Something like this:

```
var someProperty: Int

func someMethod() {
    someProperty {  // this is the syntax/ability I'm unsure about
        willSet { ...add some behavior... }
    }

    ...more stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An observer can be added to a property declared in a superclass, but not in the same class or in a class extension. You cannot declare the same property in two places in a function. The best solution I can come up with is something like this, where you have an optional closure that you evaluate in the willSet, and you only assign something to that property when you want the observing behaviour.

maybe something like:

```
private var _willSetCallback: ((Int) -> (Bool))?
var someProperty: Int {
    willSet {
        if let optionalBool = _willSetCallback?(newValue) {
             // do something
        }
    }
}

func someMethod() {
    self._willSetCallback = { newValue in
    return newValue > 0
    }
}
```

It isn't especially elegant, but it might more-or-less handle the behaviour you desire?

Comment: Ah, so it's not a native feature in the way I was inquiring about.  This solution doesn't get around the two issues I was concerned about: Every instance will have to run the `willSet` and the resulting condition within it.  I was hoping for a way to have instances not have `willSet` at all, unless they've added that observer at some later point.

Comment: Is your concern with performance? Because In the example above, you'll only be executing code if the optional closure isn't nil, and checking that the closure != nil has negligible performance ramifications.

Comment: It's partly to explore the language. However, as an example, I'm thinking about a case where I'd like to add an extension that encapsulates some logic and that property observer should be grouped in that same extension.

Comment: okay, you can't do this in an extension, although you can in a subclass. I've updated the answer a bit.